# Unlink, image into directory

Tags: image, directory, unlink

I have a file called delete.php inside where I created this code:

```
// check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    // get id value
    $id = @$_GET['id'];
    $img = @$_GET['h_image'];

   if(file_exists($img)){
    unlink('../images/'.$img);
} 

    // delete the entry
    $result = DB::table('questions')
        ->where('id', '=', $id)
        ->delete();
    // redirect back to the view page
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
    // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

The content is properly deleted from the database, but unfortunately I can not erase the image corresponding to the directory "images".

I tried with unlink, but by mistake.
How can I do?

Obviously the image must match the content to be deleted.
Thanks guys, I hope for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did so, but always from tabase but not delete the image from the directory:

Maybe I'm wrong path of the image? The GET?

```
// get id value
$id = @$_GET['id'];
$path = @$_GET['img'];

if(file_exists($path))
unlink("images/".$path);
```